# Extend view to bottom of superview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I want to animate a view inside ViewController, somewhat like the notification center as seen on the iPhone.

How does one extend the subview using the x,y and/or the height values to do this? Because I would like it to be compatible with both the 3.5 inch screens and the 4 inch screens, so it would be better not to use specific values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tested this out in my own project and confirmed that it works on varying screen sizes.

```
UIView *slidingview = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectOffset(self.view.frame, 0, -self.view.frame.size.height)];
slidingview.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[self.view addSubview:slidingview];
[UIView animateWithDuration:1 animations:^{
    slidingview.center = CGPointMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2, self.view.frame.size.height/2);
}];
```

To implement this, simply replace `slidingview` with the view you want to slide down.  You would, however, have to declare your own view using the frame I provided.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?

```
CGRect currentFrame = self.view.bounds;
UIView * slidingView = [UIView alloc] initWithFrame:(CGRect){currentFrame.origin, currentFrame.size.width, 0};
[self.view addSubview:slidingView];
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f animations:^{
    slidingView.frame = currentFrame;
}];
```

You may need to use `delay` version of `animateWithDuration...` to make animation in effect.